# Is there Sparse Matrix in Matlab allowing reading data entry in O(1) time?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

To efficiently add/delete any non-zero entry in the sparse matrix, binary-tree etc will be used to let such operation completed in O(logN) time where N is the number of non-zero entries. Thus, reading a non-zero entry can also cost O(logN) time.

However, in practice,  we may have no need to add/delete any entry on a sparse matrix A, but only need to read its non-zero entries to do matrix-vector multiplication Ax. So, I hope to read any non-zero entry of A very fast, maybe in O(1) time.

My question is, Matlab can do such thing?

Comment: It is not clear to me how it can be O(1). What's the data structure that allows such operation? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Memming In practice, we can allocate a continuous memory, then the address of any entry in the memory can be calculated in O(1) time given its index.... With address, that entry can be obtained.

Comment: If you allocate continuous memory, it's not a sparse matrix anymore, right? Sparse matrices store the nonzero entries of each column as a list. The fastest way to access an individual index of that list is, as you say, a binary search in `O(log n)`. That's the tradeoff for using a data structure that minimizes memory usage.

Comment: However, in the specific case of matrix-vector multiplication, you don't need to access non-zero elements of the matrix in arbitrary order. Rather, you take an entire column of the matrix and operate on its non-zero values sequentially, meaning that access to each **sequential** element is effectively `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible. From what I saw on the internet ([this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html) and [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)), Matlab uses  [Dictionary of keys (DOK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_(DOK)) to store sparse matrix, though I couldn't find any solid statement on that part. A dictionary has an access time of O(1) ofc.

To answer if Matlab actually does this I would suggest running some simple testing with time measuring (using `timeit` or `tic` + `toc`).